# Inheritance only for data?

Tags: inheritance, aggregation

I have class Fruit with data and logic.

Now I need a lot of different fruits, which only differ in: name, bitmap, and some other data.

Is there any sense in making a new subclass for each fruit? They have all "is a" relationship with fruit. But they don't add new behaviour or fields.

Maybe it's better just to give the fuit a "type" field, instead of subclassing it? Is anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of types of fruit are you trying to distinguish? If its just a typing diffidence I tend to use an enum value, from an enum list defined in the base class (in this case fruit) and then passed or initialized on the inheriting class's constructor.

eg

```
class Fruit
{
   public:
   enum Type { SPIKEY, RED, ROUND, SQUISHY };

   Fruit(Type type)
   {
      mType =  type;
   }

  protected:
     Type mType;

};
```

you can just define specific values in constructor for name etc

Comment: This is like kasavbere's answer but with enum values. Same comment.

Answer (score 2):

One class is sufficient, if I understand correctly. upon initialization, the name may be passed.

```
public class Fruit{
    String name;
     ...//bit map, etc
    public Fruit(String name, ...){
       this.name=name;
       ...//bit map
    }
}
```

user class:

```
 Fruit apple = new Fruit("apple", ...);
```

Comment: Yes, the question is if there's something wrong with this approach, but I guess it's the right one. Otherwise I get 50+ classes just because of data and that doesn't make any sense.